# is there a way to set the "base margin" for XgBoost in the MLR framework?

Tags: r, xgboost, mlr

I am trying to fit an XgBoost model within the MLR framework. While the framework is fairly well documented, there are some specifics of the XgBoost library that I cannot replicate within MLR, one in particular being the "base margin". 
In XgBoost library I would just set :

```
db_xgbmatrix <- xgb.DMatrix(db)
setinfo(db_xgbmatrix , "base_margin", margin)
```

and then I can just go on with the training of the model; whereas, in MLR, once I create the task and the learner:

```
tsk      <- makeRegrTask(data =  db, target = target_var)
lrn <- makeLearner("regr.xgboost", predict.type = "response", eta = 0.1,
                   max_depth = 8, min_child_weight = 20,
                   subsample = 0.75, colsample_bytree = 0.75,
                   nrounds = 100, nthread = cl_n, objective="count:poisson")
```

I'm not quite sure of where the base margin should be set. Any ideas? Is that feature implemented, and hidden somewhere?
Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0):

This isn't implemented in mlr. We don't have any plans to support it, but you're always welcome to contribute a [pull request](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3/wiki/pr-guidelines).